# How to use foreach with external API using Http in laravel?

Tags: json, laravel, foreach

I am trying to display data from external API using Http

web.php:

```
Route::resource('job', 'App\Http\Controllers\AjaxController');
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    
    $apis = Http::get("example/api/records");
    return view("job.index", [
        "apis" => json_decode($apis)
    ]);
}
```

view:

```
@foreach ($apis as $item)
<h1>{{$item->DocKey}}</h1>
@endforeach
```

I am getting the data from the api inside the view as showing below:

[image]

but i get this error:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$DocKey
```

what seems to be the problem here?

Comment: What does your debugging show? Try adding `var_dump($apis)`?

Comment: i was using the wrong URL but now im getting this error "Attempt to read property "DocKey" on string" , i think because there is another array inside this one, what should i do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller should look like:

```
$response = Http::get('http://yourdomain.com/example/api/records');
$apis = json_decode($response->body());
```